# condition in join to extract information in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables Vizite (foreign key), Medici(primary key) and i need to extract the list doctors who consulted less than 5 patients in 2017. I do this, but i don't know how to set the conditions, to get the desired result.

```
select concat(Nume,' ',Prenume) as 'Nume Medic',
    count(Pacienti_Idp) As 'Nr vizite',
    year(DataOra) as An 
    from medici
    inner join vizite on medici.idm = vizite.medici_idm
    group by (Pacienti_Idp);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should  group by the medici and filter using having

```
 select concat(Nume,' ',Prenume) as `Nume Medic`, 
    count(Pacienti_Idp) As `Nr vizite`,
    year(DataOra) as An 
from medici
inner join vizite on medici.idm = vizite.medici_idm
group by concat(Nume,' ',Prenume),  year(DataOra)
having  count(Pacienti_Idp) < 5
```

or using the alias in aggregated  function

```
 select concat(Nume,' ',Prenume) as `Nume Medic`, 
    count(Pacienti_Idp) As `Nr vizite`,
    year(DataOra) as An 
from medici
inner join vizite on medici.idm = vizite.medici_idm
group by c`Nume Medic`, An
having  `Nr vizite`< 5
```

PS don't use single queote around columns name  .. (these area use as literal)   use backticks when you need

```
    backtics: `
```